# Uniqueness of solutions to ODEs for functions of complex domain

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the ivp

$$
\tag{1}
\frac{df}{dz}=F(z,f), \hspace{1cm} f(z_0)=f_0 \hspace{1.5cm} f:\Bbb{C}\rightarrow\Bbb{C}
$$

where $f$ and $F$ are complex valued and **analytic**, then does it folow that $(1)$ has a unique solution, as it would if they were real-valued?

The specific problem I am looking at, outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829001/does-int-infty-infty-frac-mathrmexp-t2t-iz-dt-i-sqrt-pi-e) in more detail, is $\frac{df}{dz}=-2+2zf$

which arises when investigating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t-iz} dt}$

Help, as always, will be appreciated.

Comment: I just answered [this equestion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833988/under-which-conditions-a-solution-of-an-ode-is-analytic-function).

Comment: @Artem I'm having a look at the book mentioned in the comments - so is the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem extednible for functions of complex domain?

Comment: I do not know such theorem. The answer to your original question is "yes", problem (1) has a unique locally analytic solution. Proofs can be found in my answer linked above.